# delete nested category laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-relations

I used this structure to store categories.
**How can I delete all child nested categories when I delete a category?**

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test 1 | 0 |
| 2 | test 2 | 1 |
| 3 | test 3 | 2 |
| 4 | test 4 | 3 |
| 5 | test 5 | 0 |

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');

    }
}
```

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('parent_id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option: Tap into the `deleting` hook, delete all children.

```
//in your model.
protected static function boot() {
  parent::boot(); //need to call parent's boot method
  static::deleting( function ($category) {
    $category->children->each(function($cat){ //edit after comment
      $cat->delete();
    });
  });
}
```

Alternatively:

```
//in your model.
protected static function booted() { //booted method, no need to call parent boot
  static::deleting( function ($category) {
    $category->children()->delete();
  });
}
```

And in your destroy method in the controller:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, Category $category) {
   $category->delete();  //OR Category::destroy($categoryIdYouWantToDestroy)
   return "deleted";
}
```

**What happens when you call the delete method?**

Your model will dispatch `deleting` and `deleted` events. What we are doing in the boot method is listening and responding to the deleting event. It translates to when the model starts the deleting process, retrieve its children and delete those first, then delete the model.

Learn more about events:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events

Comment: Can I use this in the destroy(Request $request) method?

Comment: You can use the same logic but it's cleaner and safer to do in here, imo.

Comment: How do I call static deleting method in controller?

Comment: This should be done in the model. In the controller you just need to delete the model, and laravel will automatically handle the logic in the deleting hook.

Comment: your solution only delete selected category and one level nested.

Comment: ah! Ishould  have addressed the mass deletion. I would suggest to loop through the children and do the deletion. Will edit the anser.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply query the relationship and delete all items:

```
$category->children()->delete(); // Run this line BEFORE deleting the category itself
$category->delete();
```

Where you wannt to put these lines is up to you:

- If you only delete the catgories on one specific controllere, you can put those there
- You can hook into the catgory deletion event and perform these actions there
- You can create a method `deleteAll` in your category model and invoke it anytime you need to delete a category

Comment: your solution only delete selected category and one level nested children.

Answer (score 0):

you have two way for deleting hierarchy categories.

1. this way is so simple :

```php
public function deleteCategories(array $categories){
     $cats = [];
     foreach($categories as $category){
         $cats = array_merge($cats,$category->children);
         $category->children()->delete();
     }
     if(count($cats) > 0)
          $this->deleteCategories($cats);
     else
          return true;
}
```

2. another way :

in this way you need to a query that fetch a tree from your database.
then you can find all of IDs are under your category.
then you can delete all those IDs.
for more information about hierarchy query you can see :
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/

need more information ? let me know ;)